# How to find out which instance Marketing Cloud is on?

Tags: marketing-cloud

The [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_determine_your_marketing_cloud_instance.htm&type=5) states that you should search for the MID value of your account in the [Salesforce trust page](https://status.salesforce.com/products/Marketing_Cloud).

But that doesn't give any results. Our MID starts with 51 and there are about 80 instances BD51...
None of them match our MID.

In the account settings there is no additional information that might help (as in the case of Sales Cloud).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to go the [Salesforce trust page](https://status.salesforce.com/products/Marketing_Cloud), copy and paste your MID to the search bar and enter, it will find the corresponding instance there.

Comment: That's exactly what my question is about. I did that and it returns 0 results.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Did you copy and paste the MID to the search bar and search?

Comment: Yes, I did._____